# What does it means holding the load in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have added the jp@gc-Stepping thread group in my test script. I have setup my script as shown in the figure.

[image]

I have stepping thread group configuration in the following ways:

[image]

Currently, I have them set up only 20 threads, but while I had my thread number as 200. I had assumed it would send at least 200 requests whether it is a success or an error. But the request never reached 200, it was around 60-80 only.

What was it missing on my end?

What is the difference between the load and thread in JMeter?

Does `holding the loads in JMeter` actually, mean the JMeter has started to send the request to the server? I am a bit confused in understanding the term `hold the load`. How to estimate the time to hold the load for? Or should the business people have the estimation for this? Is it dependent upon the number of threads added?

Answer (score 0):

Hold the load means that it will keep 20 (or 200) **users**  for 4 minutes.

The **users** will be executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) as fast as they can, the number of requests per second will mostly depend on your application response time, presence of timers, etc. See [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second) article for more details.

If you're looking for the way to send 20 (or 200) **requests per second** - consider switching to [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin). However remember that the aforementioned constraints still apply:\

- JMeter must be capable of sending the requests fast enough
- Your application must be able to respond fast enough

Comment: does keeping the user also means it is sending the request to the server? how is holding the load related to ramp-up time?

Comment: A user executes Samplers upside down or according to [logic controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers), if there are Samplers which send requests - JMeter will be sending the requests. [Ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/) is for onboarding users **gradually**, this way you can correlate increasing load with other metrics, there is no relationship between ramp-up and time to hold the load, you can remove this or that phase or combine them, it depends on the workload type you want to apply